# Puzzling performance difference between ifort and gfortran

Tags: fortran

Recently, I read a [post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer) about finding integers that are perfect squares.  As I wanted to play with this, I wrote the following small program:

```
PROGRAM PERFECT_SQUARE
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER*8 :: N, M, NTOT
LOGICAL :: IS_SQUARE

N=Z'D0B03602181'
WRITE(*,*) IS_SQUARE(N)

NTOT=0
DO N=1,1000000000
  IF (IS_SQUARE(N)) THEN
    NTOT=NTOT+1
  END IF
END DO
WRITE(*,*) NTOT ! should find 31622 squares
END PROGRAM

LOGICAL FUNCTION IS_SQUARE(N)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER*8 :: N, M

! check if negative
IF (N.LT.0) THEN
  IS_SQUARE=.FALSE.
  RETURN
END IF

! check if ending 4 bits belong to (0,1,4,9)
M=IAND(N,15)
IF (.NOT.(M.EQ.0 .OR. M.EQ.1 .OR. M.EQ.4 .OR. M.EQ.9)) THEN
  IS_SQUARE=.FALSE.
  RETURN
END IF

! try to find the nearest integer to sqrt(n)
M=DINT(SQRT(DBLE(N)))
IF (M**2.NE.N) THEN
  IS_SQUARE=.FALSE.
  RETURN
END IF

IS_SQUARE=.TRUE.
RETURN
END FUNCTION
```

When compiling with `gfortran -O2`, running time is 4.437 seconds, with -O3 it is 2.657 seconds.  Then I thought that compiling with `ifort -O2` could be faster since it might have a faster `SQRT` function, but it turned out running time was now 9.026 seconds, and with `ifort -O3` the same.  I tried to analyze it using Valgrind, and the Intel compiled program indeed uses many more instructions.

My question is why? Is there a way to find out where exactly the difference comes from?

EDITS:

- gfortran version 4.6.2 and ifort version 12.0.2
- times are obtained from running `time ./a.out` and is the real/user time (sys was always almost 0)
- this is on Linux x86_64, both gfortran and ifort are 64-bit builds
- ifort inlines everything, gfortran only at -O3, but the latter assembly code is simpler than that of ifort, which uses xmm registers a lot
- fixed line of code, added `NTOT=0` before loop, should fix issue with other gfortran versions

When the complex `IF` statement is removed, gfortran takes about 4 times as much time (10-11 seconds).  This is to be expected since the statement approximately throws out about 75% of the numbers, avoiding to do the `SQRT` on them.  On the other hand, ifort only uses slightly more time.  My guess is that something goes wrong when ifort tries to optimize the `IF` statement.

EDIT2:

I tried with ifort version 12.1.2.273 it's much faster, so looks like they fixed that.

Comment: Are those wall times or CPU times? Can you paste the output of `time <program>` for each one? And were these 32-bit builds or 64-bit builds?

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the object files emitted by each compiler and comparing them?

Comment: @talonmies: no I didn't, since I don't really understand assembly.  Although running through `valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes` also gives the assembly code, but that's really complex (many differences) and depends on the level of optimization.

Comment: Did you try more aggressive optimization levels? They might be worth it.

Comment: Are you sure your program is correct? With more recent versions of gfortran than 4.5 i get different answers.

Comment: @Vladimir: which optimizations would you suggest beyond `-O3`?  That gfortran 4.5 gives different answers is strange, what do you get?

Comment: A similar question last month had this interesting answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346126/189050

Comment: @Vladimir: I fixed the program, `NTOT` wasn't initialized. @Deditos: yes, I read that post and indeed this can have an effect.  Only in this case ifort seems to completely choke on that complex IF-statement

Comment: @steabert Now the results are correct. Just fyi I get 14.6s for gfortran 4.5, 10.7s for gfortran 4.6 and 4.7 and 14.2s for Solaris Studio 12.3.

Comment: @Vladimir: nice, thnx.  Do you by chance have ifort to try? :)  This seems rather an ifort problem (see edit).

Comment: @steabert unfortunatly no, I don't have the licence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What compiler versions are you using? 
Interestingly, it looks like a case where there is a performance regression from 11.1 to 12.0 -- e.g. for me, 11.1 (ifort -fast square.f90) takes 3.96s, and 12.0 (same options) took 13.3s.
gfortran (4.6.1) (-O3) is still faster (3.35s).
I have seen this kind of a regression before, although not quite as dramatic.
BTW, replacing the if statement with

```
is_square = any(m == [0, 1, 4, 9])
if(.not. is_square) return
```

makes it run twice as fast with ifort 12.0, but slower in gfortran and ifort 11.1.

It looks like part of the problem is that 12.0 is overly aggressive in trying to vectorize things: adding

```
!DEC$ NOVECTOR
```

right before the DO loop (without changing anything else in the code) cuts the run time down to 4.0 sec.

Also, as a side benefit: if you have a multi-core CPU, try adding -parallel to the ifort command line :)

Comment: See edit: with ifort version 12.1.2.273 it worked.  Also, there is a difference when compiling and linking seperately or on one line, strange.  Now I have: gfortran 3.1 s with or without your `any` statement, and ifort 3.3 s original and 5.0 s with the `any` statement.

Comment: yes, I think the reason `any` made things faster in 12.0 was by preventing vectorization. Difference between compiling separately and on one line I think suggests something like that instruction cache issue might be going on. Also, the whole thing would speed up a lot if you use single instead of double precision, and I think also if you modify the function to return 1 or 0 and add results up instead of having an `if` statement (conditional statements in loops are often bad for performance).

Comment: thnx for the comments especially the addition hint, I'll try that. As for double precision: I need it to get the correct square root for very large integers.  This was just an exploration of integer square root, to see if it can be done faster with other methods, but it turned out that the sqrt instruction can't be beaten...

Comment: well, turns out that with the integer is_square function and simple addition in the loop, the code runs slower, i.e. 3.9s instead of 3.1s :)

Comment: I see. Just tried -- for me this also happened, but only with gfortran (not ifort), and only when if function was declared as integer(8) -- with machine default integer the speed is the same. No improvement though -- I guess there are quite a few jumps there already, so one more does not really matter :)

Comment: The conspiracy theorist will point out that Intel did this so they can claim v12 is faster than v11.